# Loading JSON data in QGIS and matching it with GeoJSON layer on `id`

Tags: qgis, geojson, json, map-matching

I am new to QGIS and I'm trying to add a JSON file with data to a GeoJSON layer by using the same "id" they have in the `"properties"` field.

I have a GeoJSON file with ids:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              4653793.42338882,
              5124889.5345974155
            ],
           ...
           [
              4653796.093490953,
              5124881.326846274
            ],
            [
              4653793.42338882,
              5124889.5345974155
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": 72757,
        "parent_id": 69911,
        "common_id": "61",
        "common_name": "81-61",
        "has_children": false,
        "shape_type_id": 4,
        "shape_type_name": "Precinct",
        "value": "No Data",
        "color": null,
        "title_location": "Precinct: 81-61"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And a JSON file with ids :

```
{
  "indicator": {
    "is_summary": true,
    "name": null,
    "name_abbrv": "Overall Results",
    "description": "Overall Results",
    "number_format": null,
    "scales": [
      {
        "name": "No Data",
        "color": "#CCCCCC"
      }
    ],
    "scale_colors": [
      "#CCCCCC"
    ],
    "switcher_indicator_id": null
  },
  "view_type": "summary",
  "shape_data": [
    ...
    [
      {
        "shape_values": {
          "shape_id": 72757,
          "shape_name": "81-61",
          "parent_id": null,
          "value": "Margvelashvili (Georgian Dream)",
          "color": "#1b70af",
          "number_format": null,
          "precincts_completed_precent": null,
          "title": "Results",
          "title_abbrv": null,
          "title_location": null,
          "title_precincts_completed": null
        }
      },
      {
        "summary_data": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 5538710,
              "value": "54.46",
              "formatted_value": "54.46",
              "number_format": "%",
              "rank": 1,
              "color": "#1b70af",
              "indicator_type_id": 2,
              "indicator_type_name": "Results",
              "core_indicator_id": 119,
              "indicator_id": 2701,
              "indicator_name_unformatted": "Giorgi Margvelashvili",
              "indicator_name": "Giorgi Margvelashvili (Georgian Dream)",
              "indicator_name_abbrv": "Margvelashvili (Georgian Dream)",
              "has_openlayers_rule_value": false,
              "visible": true
            },
            {
              "id": 5538692,
              "value": "29.34",
              "formatted_value": "29.34",
              "number_format": "%",
              "rank": 2,
              "color": "#ca4748",
              "indicator_type_id": 2,
              "indicator_type_name": "Results",
              "core_indicator_id": 121,
              "indicator_id": 2719,
              "indicator_name_unformatted": "Davit Bakradze",
              "indicator_name": "Davit Bakradze (UNM)",
              "indicator_name_abbrv": "Bakradze (UNM)",
              "has_openlayers_rule_value": false,
              "visible": true
            },
            {
              "id": 5538701,
              "value": "9.15",
              "formatted_value": "9.15",
              "number_format": "%",
              "rank": 3,
              "color": "#079fe2",
              "indicator_type_id": 2,
              "indicator_type_name": "Results",
              "core_indicator_id": 125,
              "indicator_id": 2731,
              "indicator_name_unformatted": "Nino Burjanadze",
              "indicator_name": "Nino Burjanadze (United Geo)",
              "indicator_name_abbrv": "Burjanadze (United Geo)",
              "has_openlayers_rule_value": false,
              "visible": true
            },
            {
              "id": 5538697,
              "value": "4.93",
              "formatted_value": "4.93",
              "number_format": "%",
              "rank": 4,
              "color": "#ca9c6c",
              "indicator_type_id": 2,
              "indicator_type_name": "Results",
              "core_indicator_id": 117,
              "indicator_id": 2689,
              "indicator_name_unformatted": "Giorgi Targamadze",
              "indicator_name": "Giorgi Targamadze (CDM)",
              "indicator_name_abbrv": "Targamadze (CDM)",
              "has_openlayers_rule_value": false,
              "visible": true
            },
            {
              "id": 5538689,
              "value": "0.47",
              "formatted_value": "0.47",
              "number_format": "%",
              "rank": 5,
              "color": "#e0e4bf",
              "indicator_type_id": 2,
              "indicator_type_name": "Results",
              "core_indicator_id": 105,
              "indicator_id": 2617,
              "indicator_name_unformatted": "Giorgi Liluashvili",
              "indicator_name": "Giorgi Liluashvili (Init Grp)",
              "indicator_name_abbrv": "Liluashvili (Init Grp)",
              "has_openlayers_rule_value": false,
              "visible": true
            }
          ],
          "visible": true,
          "has_openlayers_rule_value": true,
          "total_ranks": 12,
          "has_duplicates": true
        }
      },
      {
        "data_item": {
          "id": 5538680,
          "value": "426",
          "formatted_value": "426",
          "number_format": null,
          "rank": null,
          "color": null,
          "indicator_type_id": 1,
          "indicator_type_name": null,
          "core_indicator_id": 15,
          "indicator_id": 2523,
          "indicator_name_unformatted": "Total Voter Turnout (#)",
          "indicator_name": "Total Voter Turnout (#)",
          "indicator_name_abbrv": "Total Turnout (#)",
          "has_openlayers_rule_value": false,
          "visible": true
        }
      },
      {
        "data_item": {
          "id": 5538681,
          "value": "38.38",
          "formatted_value": "38.38",
          "number_format": "%",
          "rank": null,
          "color": null,
          "indicator_type_id": 1,
          "indicator_type_name": null,
          "core_indicator_id": 16,
          "indicator_id": 2529,
          "indicator_name_unformatted": "Total Voter Turnout (%)",
          "indicator_name": "Total Voter Turnout (%)",
          "indicator_name_abbrv": "Total Turnout (%)",
          "has_openlayers_rule_value": false,
          "visible": false
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

They both have the same id in properties: `"id": 72757` for `kobuleti_precincts` and `"shape_id": 72757` for `kobuleti_results`. I know how to load the first one but I don't know how to load the second one with JSON data and match it with the first one.

So far I've tried to do it manually:

```
precinct_json.features.map(function(feature){
    var matchedArray = precinct_results.shape_data.filter(function(feature2){
        return feature.properties.id === feature2[0].shape_values.shape_id;
    });
    if(matchedArray && matchedArray[0]){
console.log(matchedArray[0].summary_data)


        for(var attr in matchedArray[0].summary_data){
            feature.properties[attr] = matchedArray[0].summary_data[attr];
        }
    }
});
```

But it returns an `undefined` array.

But I get:

```
(64) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

## Data to reproduce the example

All the data comes from [this map](https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/indicator_type/2/view_type/summary/change_shape/true/parent_clickable/false/shape/69911/shape_type/3?data_set_id=111&data_type=official) that I got with the network tool in the `inspect element` like one can see for another map here :

[image]

Comment: Loading data in QGIS usually is a simple "drag & drop".